# How to Denormalize object with java.util.stream

Tags: java

I have the following objects:

```
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Collection<Order> orders;

    public int getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public Collection<Order> getOrders() {return orders;}
    public void setOrders(Collection<Order> orders) {this.orders = orders;}
}

public class Order {
    private int id;
    private String item;

    public int getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getItem() {return item;}
    public void setItem(String item) {this.item = item;}
}

public class CustomerOrderDto {
    private int customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private String orderId;
    private String orderItem;

    public int getCustomerId() {return customerId;}
    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {this.customerId = customerId;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getOrderId() {return orderId;}
    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {this.orderId = orderId;}
    public String getOrderItem() {return orderItem;}
    public void setOrderItem(String orderItem) {this.orderItem = orderItem;}
}
```

So if I have a **Customer** object with two **Orders** the result would be a list of two **CustomerOrderDto** objects.

I can obviously do this with for loops, but I am looking for a more elegant solution using Java streams.
My background is .NET where I can easily do this with LINQ, but this my first java project and I wanted to see if I can do something similar here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private List<Customer.CustomerOrderDto> customerOrderDtoList(Customer customer){
    Collection<Customer.Order> orders = customer.getOrders();
    return orders.stream()
                 .map(order -> createCustomerOrderDto(customer, order))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Customer.CustomerOrderDto createCustomerOrderDto(Customer customer, Customer.Order order){
    Customer.CustomerOrderDto dto = new Customer.CustomerOrderDto();

    return dto;
}
```

Comment: The above should work. In createCustomerOrderDto map your Customer and Order fields to CustomerOrderDto object

Answer (score 0):

If you want access your object with foreach

```
orders.forEach((k)->System.out.println("Item : " + k));
```

More examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/).